# How to call WFSStartUp via C# application

Tags: c#, cen-xfs

I use this code for call `WFSStartUp` via `C#` program

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public unsafe struct WFSVERSION
{
    public ushort wVersion;
    public ushort wLowVersion;
    public ushort wHighVersion;
    public fixed char szDescription[256 + 1];
    public fixed char szSystemStatus[256 + 1];
}

[DllImport("msxfs.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = XFSConstants.CALLINGCONVENTION)]
public static extern int WFSStartUp(int dwVersionsRequired, ref WFSVERSION lpWFSVersion);

WFSVERSION m_Version = new WFSVERSION();

int requestVersion = 0x00010202;

int hResult = WFSStartUp(requestVersion, ref m_Version);
```

the return value `hResult` is Ok but `m_Version.szDescription` not correct (`m_Version.szDescription[0] = 'W'`, `m_Version.szDescription[1] = 0`, ...)

How to solve this problem?

Comment: when i call this function from C code szDescription field fill with "WOSA/XFS API v3.00/v2.00" and szSystemStatus field is empty

Comment: Solved
Change struct WFSVERSION

public unsafe struct WFSVERSION
{
 public ushort wVersion;
    public ushort wLowVersion;
    public ushort wHighVersion;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256 + 1)]
    public string szDescription;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256 + 1)]
    public string szSystemStatus;
}